# Последний объём из moex

Tags: python, api, get

Не могу найти, как получить последний объём из moex..
Что нашлось...

requests.get('http://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities/YNDX/candles.json?from=2023-11-22&interval=1').json()

Это видимо позволяет определить, начиная с from 500 значений. Меня интересует как получить самые последние данные.